# Access GET FromQuery attribute

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have written the following API method that accepts a `FromQuery`. What I need to do is to access this get method as a URL. So it'll appear as:

```
https://localhost:7444/v1/api/Mycontrooler/Getcontent?MyName=james&MySchool=TensSchool
```

What changes to my API method/ or URL should I make to access GET method as a URL.

What do I see now: This localhost page can’t be found.

How can I resolve this?

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("Getcontent")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Getcontent([FromQuery] MyModel model)
    {

            return Ok(model);
        
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you define the variables `MyName` and `MySchool` instead of `MyModel`?

Comment: have you done any searches on the following[FromRoute], [FromQuery], [FromBody] for example?

Answer (score 0):

> What changes to my API method/ or URL should I make to access GET
> method as a URL.

Well, you should use [`Attribute Routing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#attribute-routing-for-rest-apis) in this scenario. So if you set the route defination on top of your `controller calss` as `[Route("v1/api/[controller]")]` therefore, you can  get your URL as

```
https://localhost:7444/v1/api/Mycontroller/Getcontent?MyName=james&MySchool=TensSchool
```

You can refer to below example:

**Controller Route:**

```
    [Route("v1/api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class MyContentController : ControllerBase
    {

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet("Getcontent")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Getcontent([FromQuery] MyModel model)
        {

            return Ok(model);

        }

    }
```

**Note:**  In this defination `[Route("v1/api/[controller]")]` your `API version` is fixed. However, if you would like to make it dynamic then you can redefine as below:

**Dynamic API version in Route:**

```
    [ApiVersion("1.0")]
    [Route("v{apiVersion}/api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class MyContentController : ControllerBase
    {

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet("Getcontent")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Getcontent([FromQuery] MyModel model)
        {

            return Ok(model);

        }

    }
```

**Model:**

public class MyModel
{
public string MyName { get; set; }
public string MySchool { get; set; }
}

**Output:**

[image]

For more details you could refer to our [`official document heree`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#attribute-routing-for-rest-apis)